# Is JsonDeserializer#deserialize(...) allowed to return null?

Tags: jackson

A Web service returns "location" objects with properties that map almost 1:1 to the fields of `android.location.Address`.  I've written a custom deserializer to handle them, and it works.

Occasionally the Web service returns garbage locations, i.e., latitude 0.0, longitude 0.0, other fields empty strings.  I'd like these garbage locations to be deserialized as a Java `null`.

**Is `JsonDeserializer#deserialize(...)` allowed to return `null`?**

I haven't simply tested this myself because:

- The behavior of a particular version of Jackson is not a guarantee unless it's documented.
- It's quicker to write this question than mock the bogus input or write a separate test app.
- The answer might be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonDeserializer#deserialize` is allowed to return `null` by the design of `JsonDeserializer` class, although it is not explicitly mentioned in the Javadoc of the method.

This can be assumed by the existence, default implementation and documentation of methods `JsonDeserializer#getNullValue` and `JsonDeserializer#getEmptyValue`.

These methods can be called to produce return values for `deserialize` e.g.

```
return getNullValue();
```

when the `JsonToken` is `null` or empty respectively. By default they return `null` and that will be returned by `deserialize`.

See [here](http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2015/01/01/building-a-custom-jackson-deserializer/) an example with `getNullValue`.